# Открытие ссылок в стороннем браузере - Flutter, WebView

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview

Есть WebView и в нём я открываю свою веб-страницу. В моей веб-странице есть ссылка на Википедию (`<a href="https://ru.wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</a>`). Эта ссылка открывается у меня в WebView, а нужно чтобы в стороннем браузере. Причём, открывать нужно ссылки именно такого типа, а сами страницы моего сайта внутри WebView. Как это можно реализовать? Использую [данный](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) плагин. Заранее спасибо за ответ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `webview_flutter` в связке с [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher).
Нужно проверить url и вызвать `_launchUrl`.

```
WebView(
  initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
  navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request){
    if(request.url.startsWith('https://flutter.dev')){
      return NavigationDecision.navigate;
    }
    _launchURL(request.url);
    return NavigationDecision.prevent;
  },
)
```

Функция открытия ссылки в браузере:

```
_launchURL(String url) async {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```